# google +1 button not showing up

Tags: google-plus-one

I've added the required tags, but it is still not showing. I've added this in head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
  {lang: 'lt', parsetags:'explicit'}
</script>
```

and this in the body:

```
<g:plusone href="http://www.fanuspinta.lt/katalogas/lietuva-mar%C5%A1kin%C4%97liai-31"></g:plusone>
```

At first I thought it didn't show up because I was using a local server, but now it's in production, and still not showing.

URL in case: http://www.fanuspinta.lt/katalogas/lietuva-mar%C5%A1kin%C4%97liai-31

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: it's working fine over here ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a [html5 tag](http://code.google.com/apis/+1button/#plusonetag) like shown here without the data-href attribute, dynamically added it afterwards (when the lightbox was loaded) and [explicitely loaded](http://code.google.com/apis/+1button/#example-explicit-load) the div containing the plusone code at the end.